# Boolean does not resolve on comparing integer

Tags: python

Something is wrong with comparison on my Python script and I can´t figure out what is going wrong.
I read in a JSON File with some data which works fine and also read in a RFID Tag.

If I try to compare if rfid scan is contained in JSON it does not seem to work even if it is the same value and datatype.

Code:

```
try:
    id, text = reader.read()
    print(id, text)
    with open('rfid_chips.json') as file:
        data = json.loads(file.read())
    file.close()

    for value in data:
        print("From Json:")
        print(type(value["userid"]))
        print(value["rfid_number"])
        print("From RFID Scanner")
        print(type(id))
        print(id)
        if (value["rfid_number"] == id):
            print("Found!")
            print("RFID Number:" + id + " has userid: " + value["userid"])
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

Output with same value in vonsole:

```
From RFID Scanner
<class 'int'>
651339019345
From Json:
<class 'int'>
651339019345
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit** Update with JSON File:

```
[
    {
        "rfid_number": "123",
        "userid": 14,
        "created_at": "2022-01-29T17:19:10.722Z",
        "modified_at": null
    },
    {
        "rfid_number": "651339019345",
        "userid": 15,
        "created_at": "2022-01-29T17:20:43.762Z",
        "modified_at": null
    },
    {
        "rfid_number": "839752300892",
        "userid": 17,
        "created_at": "2022-01-29T22:58:30.177Z",
        "modified_at": null
    },
    {
        "rfid_number": "906776623571",
        "userid": 19,
        "created_at": "2022-01-31T14:13:58.406Z",
        "modified_at": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Try seeing if the difference == 0?

Comment: Your code would print `From Json` first; your output prints it second. What else is different between the code you have shown and the code you actually running?

Comment: Also for the JSON file, you are printing the type of one dict entry but the value of another. Kind of makes me think `value["rfid_number"]` is actually a `str` value.

Comment: You should provide an example Json file and try to build a [mre]. A problem is much easier to fix if we can reproduce...

Comment: @chepner it is because the first print is not relevant for this since it is another entry which would resolve in false (from json class int 1234) after rfid which is always obviously the same id following by other json data from the file.

Comment: JSON Example added in edit above. @chepner that would make sense but why is type printing out "int" on all values?

Comment: `rfid_number` is *not* a number; it's a string (see the quotes?). Like I said, you aren't printing the type of `rfid_number`; you're printing the type of `userid`, which *is* an `int`.

Comment: @chepner uff.... my god sometimes the simplest mistakes are not clear visible at the time.... thank you very much and sorry for bothering